# query strings are persisting across all controllers in error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, parameters

I have a rails 3 application where I am passing some string queries like this:

```
<%= link_to "All", work_orders_path(params.merge({:status_filter => "E", :sort_filter => params[:sort_filter]})) %>
```

Everything works persistence wise in my views for work_order which is what these parameters are intended for (sorting and filtering existing work orders.)

The problem that I'm having is that when I go to add a new work order with a link_to, or attempt a link_to to another controller, the `:status_filter` and `:sort_filter` both are persisting, causing a routing error.

For example when I want to hit the index to view all technicians (of which these are not applicable I get

> No route matches {:sort_filter=>nil, :status_filter=>"E",
>   :controller=>"technicians"}

I've looked everywhere for a solution but as of yet I've been unable to come up with anything. I've tried `params.delete`, no dice. I know there must be an easy way to clear these from the URL in the `link_to` but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Seems like you're mutating the `params` value. Are you sure you're only using `merge` with it and not `merge!` or `update`?

Comment: didn't really understand the problem, they are persisting between two different views? or the problem happens when you click the All link?

Comment: Not using merge! or update. The problem is they're persisting in every link_to (even in different controllers) in the entire application and as of now I've been unable to clear them.

Comment: I just tried to strip off the unwanted params using params.except in my link_to and it still isn't working right.

Comment: Have you perhaps implemented `default_url_options` somewhere?

Comment: I figured out that these links for all my navigation are in my application.html.erb, so any params I use there are carried across the entire app. I still haven't figured out why. I moved these links to the index.html.erb file in work_orders and now everything else works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that these links for all my navigation are in my application.html.erb, so any params I use there are carried across the entire app. I still haven't figured out why. I moved these links to the index.html.erb file in work_orders and now everything else works.